# What are these Outlook Folders used for CrmEmailMessagesFailedAutoTracking and CrmEmailMessagesPendingLinking?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Interesting question from Customer.

In Outlook, When we have Outlook plugin for CRM enable, There are 2 out of the box folders been created under Search Folders in Outlook.

They are

1. CrmEmailMessagesFailedAutoTracking
2. CrmEmailMessagesPendingLinking

Does any one have Idea what exactly it is used for?

From the naming itself I can infer it either keeps failed auto tracking email and pending links emails.

But when I try to look into Search criteria for these folder, outlook has disabled search criteria for those folders.

[image]

Comment: Did you find anything extra?

Comment: Nothing new as you mentioned in your answer it’s for internal use for Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they are by-products of Microsoft inter-product syncing technique, in this case maybe used for retry attempts while syncing the emails between Outlook & CRM.

Strictly they are for internal use & that’s why it’s restricted.